# Empty PGPKeyRing or PGPKeyRingCollection in Bouncy Castle

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp, key-management

How to create an empty PGPKeyRing or PGPKeyRingCollection in Bouncy Castle ?

Comment: I was trying this PGPSecretKeyRingCollection aSecretKeyRingCollection = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection("")

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

PGPSecretKeyRingCollection aSecretKeyRingCollection = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(new ArrayList<>());